# Compiling coffee binaries

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, bin, shebang

If I'm writing my entire project in CoffeeScript, how do I write my "binary" files?

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
# My program sits here
```

Then, once compiled, I loose the shebang:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
// My program sits here
```

I was hoping it would turn into something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// My program sits here
```

Is it possible? Or do I need to rethink how I'm working.

Comment: After a bit of investigation it looks like I have to make myself a script to add this manually.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the script?

Comment: Hey there... I've actually been using a totally different approach these days. What I do is split my project in to two directories `src` and `build`. Within my `src` directory lives all my CoffeeScript which get's built in to the `build` directory as JavaScript. I then have one more directory called `bin` in which lives any "binary" files. Each file simple requires something from the build directory... IE: `require('../build/bin/my_script.js');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you surmise, you probably want a script to help you add the necessary shebang line. I usually create a [Cakefile](http://coffeescript.org/#cake) task to do the necessary compilation and add the appropriate first line.

Comment: yep. That's exactly how I did it. After compiling the script then examines the package.json for any binary files and makes sure they have the correct shebang.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to NOT put a .coffee extension on your "binary" file and to not compile it.

I also recommend that you not place any signficant logic in the binary. Rather, just have the binary kick off the full source.

In general, every one of my binaries sits in a `/bin` directory off the root of my project and it has these two lines only (like my CoffeeDocTest project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/coffeedoctest/blob/master/bin/coffeedoctest)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
require(__dirname + '/../src/coffeedoctest')
```

You'll also want to run `chmod 755 <filename>` on it to make it executable.

Look [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/coffeedoctest/blob/master/src/coffeedoctest.coffee) for an example of how the main `coffeedoctest.coffee` starts off and handles command line options, etc.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. The person asking this question wants to write a binary in coffeescript, but expects to distribute it in javascript. What you are suggesting would required that coffeescript is installed on all machines which try to run the binary.

Comment: He doesn't say anything about "distribute" but even if he was, command line tools are generally for other developers not users. My thinking was that if you have node, then you have npm, and if you put coffee-script as a dev-dependency in the package.json, the developer users will also have it... if you listed it as a regular dependency, then regular users would also have it. I browserify a package for the browser, but I find it's easier/better to leave command line scripts in original CoffeeScript form and not worry about the runtime compile step.

Comment: That's nice. You ignored me completely, and still haven't even noticed what the actual issue here is.